# How to discard IUpdateSearcher::BeginSearch

Tags: c++, winapi, interface, com, wuapi

I am going to enumerate not installed updates with [Windows Update Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387099(v=vs.85).aspx). And I have one question. Is that a way to discard/stop [BeginSearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386519(v=vs.85).aspx) method (searching process). I have tried to stop search process with [EndSearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386522(v=vs.85).aspx)  but it does not stop it. Thanks.

Comment: How do you know EndSearch doesn't stop the search? What happens? What does EndSearch return?

Comment: EndSearch does not return. Program just stops on EndSearch and waits until process is completed. Is that correct behavior?

Comment: Given that you get an ISearchResults out of it, I assume the answer is yes; look into ISearchJob::RequestAbort()? (Call it first, then EndSearch(), then release the ISearchResults as that should just give you a ResultCode of orcAborted... Follow the documentation's hyperlinks =P )

Comment: Thanks man. This is what i need!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IUpdateSearcher::EndSearch()` waits for the search to complete first. You can explicitly request the search to stop early by first calling `ISearchJob::RequestAbort()` on the `ISearchJob` you get from `IUpdateSearcher::BeginSearch()`. After doing that, the `ISearchResults` returned from `EndSearch()` should have a `ResultCode` of `orcAborted`, and you should be safe with just releasing it. (You should still call `EndSearch()`, because the abort operation is still asynchronous, as hinted by the name "request abort".)